# How to make django crispy form to hide a particular field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to make my `date_modified` field as hidden since I have passed `datetime.now` parameter on defining `date_modified` field in model.

`model.py`

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

`views.py`

```
class GuideFormUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Guide
    fields = ['name', 'sno', 'date_modified']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Guides')
```

corresponding form `forms.py` looks like

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'Guideform-edit' object.pk %}"
              class="post-form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<button type="submit" value="Upload" class="save btn btn-default btn-primary center-block">Update</button>

        </form>
```

This form displays `date_modified` field. But I don't want this field on frontend instead I want the value of this field in model or db_table should get updated. I know how to hide this particular field in jquery but I don't want to touch those js tools. Is there any way to make `crispy` to exclude that particular field like `{{ form|crispy|exclude:date_modified }}` ..

Comment: Permanently or temporarily?

Comment: I want that field to hide only on that particular form..

Comment: "corresponding form forms.py looks like" it is .html template. I think you do not have forms.py as you have not defined a custom form.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir ya, I don't have `forms.py`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using Generic Form that your `UpdateView` will use implicitly, create your custom Form. And in your custom Form change the widget of the `date_modified` field.

In your forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, HiddenInput
class GuideForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GuideForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_modified'].widget = HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'sno', 'date_modified', )
        model = models.Guide
```

In your views.py

```
class GuideFormUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Guide
    form_class = forms.GuideForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Guides')
```

To automatically update `date_modified` whenever you update the record, you need to use attributes `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` instead of `default`. See [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datefield). So your model will be

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

Comment: is that we need to define `Guide` model in both views and forms.py?

Comment: By define if you mean statements `model=Guide` in both `class GuideForm(forms.ModelForm):` and `class GuideFormUpdateView(UpdateView):` then yes in both.

Comment: Just now I noticed that if do an update, my `date_modified` field won't get updated. I need to update it manually. Is there any way? Think I need to overwrite the POST method.

Comment: Actually i think what you need is `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` attributes of `DateTimeField` instead of `datetime.now`. I am updating my answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj also if you want a quick solution (except `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`) then see @doru's answer. Although I like to keep my forms code in my `forms.py` instead of directly customizing it in my `views.py`.

Comment: I solved the date_modified problem by overriding the save method.

Comment: Why not use `auto_now`? Although you can do it by overriding save method.

Comment: I saw a post which says, admin page won't show this field when auto_now is added.

Comment: Cannot comment on that as I have not tested it myself, will test it later, but glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 7):

You can hide a field in a form class like so:

```
Field('field_name', type="hidden")
```

Where `Field` is from `crispy_forms.layout`

Don't forget that if he field cannot be left empty, you'll still need to pass an appropriate value before saving it.

**Abstract example:**

```
class GuideFormHiddenField(GuideFormUpdateView):
    def __init__(self, *args, *kwargs):

        Field('date_modified', type="hidden")
```

This is the easiest way. You can of course make an entirely new form, or implement your fields individual, and use a condition to determine the visibility of a certain field; which would be something like  `if User.is_authenticated(): ...` .

Comment: so, I need to create a separate Form class?

Comment: You can either do that, or put this in a condition; or change your implementation when posting the form, or inheriting the form class and adding this to it. There are plenty of ways you can do this without creating an entirely new form. The alternative is to hide it using JavaScript upon implementation.

Comment: I'll add a brief example.

Comment: pls, add the above code in a file (forms.py), since I donno how.. And also I need to include that particular form class in `GuideFormUpdateView`.

Comment: I cannot enclose `.py` to my messages, plus, I don't have your entire database, your view, URL, admin, model and settings to do so. But I gave you the solution, I'm sure you can work it out. Note that you can manipulate classes inside functions, although it's better you don't.

Comment: is that no need to invoke the base class init method?

Comment: Well if your base class had one, then yes. Do it like: `super(GuideFormHiddenField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I added the above line before `Field(`. BUt no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
from django.forms.models import modelform_factory

class GuideFormUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Guide
    form_class = modelform_factory(Guide, widgets={"date_modified": HiddenInput })
    fields = ['name', 'sno', 'date_modified']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Guides')
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory) `modelform_factory`.